# Should I use aevalsrc or anullsrc? I got flooded with "cur_dts is invalid st:0" or "Delay between the first packet", encoding stalls at frame 127

Tags: python, ffmpeg

Context: this command is generated with a python script, it aims at concatenating different small videos of different format, with a 0.5s pause, considering some video don't have an audio track.

```
ffmpeg.exe
-report
-i
input0.mp4
-i
input1.mp4
-i
input2.mp4
-i
input3.mp4
-i
input4.mp4
-i
input5.mp4
-i
input6.mp4
-i
input7.mp4
-i
input8.mp4
-f
lavfi
-i
color=c=black:s=480x270:d=0.5:r=24,format=yuv420p
-f
lavfi
-i
anullsrc
-filter_complex_script
filter_complex_script.txt
-map
[final_video]
-map
[final_audio]
-c:a
aac
concatenated-2022-04-27--23-53.mp4
```

--

```
[0]fps=24[fps0];
[fps0]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:-1:-1,setsar=1[rescaled0];
[1]fps=24[fps1];
[fps1]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:-1:-1,setsar=1[rescaled1];
[2]fps=24[fps2];
[fps2]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:-1:-1,setsar=1[rescaled2];
[3]fps=24[fps3];
[fps3]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:-1:-1,setsar=1[rescaled3];
[4]fps=24[fps4];
[fps4]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:-1:-1,setsar=1[rescaled4];
[5]fps=24[fps5];
[fps5]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:-1:-1,setsar=1[rescaled5];
[6]fps=24[fps6];
[fps6]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:-1:-1,setsar=1[rescaled6];
[7]fps=24[fps7];
[fps7]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:-1:-1,setsar=1[rescaled7];
[8]fps=24[fps8];
[fps8]scale=480:270:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=480:270:-1:-1,setsar=1[rescaled8];
[rescaled0][10:a][9:v][10:a][rescaled1][10:a][9:v][10:a][rescaled2][10:a][9:v][10:a][rescaled3][10:a][9:v][10:a][rescaled4][10:a][9:v][10:a][rescaled5][5:a][9:v][10:a][rescaled6][6:a][9:v][10:a][rescaled7][7:a][9:v][10:a][rescaled8][8:a]concat=n=17:v=1:a=1[final_video][final_audio]
```

I either have thousands of
`[mp4 @ 000002132cefe100] Delay between the first packet and last packet in the muxing queue is 10007800 > 10000000: forcing output`

when I use

`-f lavfi -i anullsrc`
so I tried using `-f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0:n=1`

instead, I have have thousands of

`cur_dts is invalid st:0 (0) [init:1 i_done:0 finish:0] (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)`

The encoding "stalls" at frame 127, it keeps doing things, but the frame counter doesn't increment.

Here are the inputs:

I skipped the yuvj420p input as it generated warnings (looks like it's not a big problem)

[image]

Here is a log (I trimmed it a bit): (I think it's a bit large for stackoverflow)

https://bpa.st/HB7A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Limit the anullsrc duration.

`-f lavfi -t 0.5 -i anullsrc`

The concat filter pads shorter streams in each segment to match the duration of the longer stream. With no anullsrc limiter, its duration is infinite, so that concat segment never terminates.

Comment: This is good for the pauses, but what about streams without an audio track?

Comment: You can use this anullsrc for those too, and concat will pad with silence as needed.